# Finite normal extensions

Tags: galois-theory, fields

Suppose that $K$ is a finite field extension of $F$. Is the following equivalent to the extension being normal?

> If $L$ is an extension of $K$ and $\sigma:K\to L$ fixes $F$, then $\sigma(K) = K$.

I know that there is a similar version where the extension is not necessarily finite and L is just the algebraic closure of F. But I don't want to assume that algebraic closures always exist. I believe that I can easily prove the statement above, but I am just surprised that I haven't seen it anywhere since it seems pretty basic.

Answer (score 1):

**Edited**

This is essentially 23.14 (3) of [https://www.math.leidenuniv.nl/~psh/GaloisTheory.pdf](https://www.math.leidenuniv.nl/%7Epsh/GaloisTheory.pdf) when $L$ is an algerbaic closure so it is somewhere in the literature. However given that you want to avoid algebraic closures you should be able to avoid infinite extensions by taking $L$ to be the normal closure of $K/F$.

**Old answer**

No this is not true and the statement doesn't even make sense. If $K \neq L$ how can an embedding $K \to L$ be an automorphism? Automorphisms by definition have the same field as domain and codomain.

Comment: Of course you are correct. I edited the question and now it should make more sense.